# responding: Invalid_request when requesting token from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to utilize Google's authorization services this [guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse). 
I'm having trouble trading the code in for a token from the server.

```
var token_request='?code='+code+
    '&client_id='+client_id+
    '&client_secret='+client_secret+
    '&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+
    '&grant_type=authorization_code';

options = {
    host: "accounts.google.com",
    path: '/o/oauth2/token'+token_request,
    method: "POST"
}

var tokenRequest = https.request(options, function(res){
    var resp = "";
    res.on('data', function(data){
        resp+= data;
    })
    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log(resp);
    })
    res.on('error', function(err){
        console.log("\033[;33mIt's an Error.\033[0;39m");
        console.log(err);
    })
}).end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) site that you should use 'method: "GET"' instead of 'method: "POST"' since your values are in the query string.

**EDIT:**

According to the comments, I would say that you have to rework your code in order for it to work properly.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but backwards, it should be POST but instead of adding the token_request to the url as in GET it needs to be added to the body.  See: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback for the syntax.  Though imho you should use the request module, since it's a much better api.

Comment: With your current code, I think you just need to change POST to GET, and I think that should do it. Else you would have to rework you code in order to do a POST request.

Comment: @jsterman, I would agree with you, but Google requires a POST request.  saying that get isn't allowed: [GET example](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token).

Comment: @generalhenry I'll try reworking it into the body of the request. Normally I would just use a module but I'm using the project to develop my node skills and taking every opportunity I can to see how it works. Otherwise yes, I agree. It would be much cleaner to use a mod.

Comment: re-work it is.I learned something about POST requests in Node along the way. (POST requests are sent with the body)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am trying to do the same thing with difficulty. Not withstanding that is it worth trying googleapis.

You need to use npm to install the google apis

npm install googleapis

see https://npmjs.org/package/googleapis

for the documentation